# Markdown with custom syntax?

Tags: python, markdown

I'm using python and using markdown. Is there a simple way to add a custom syntax? I want something like `[ABC]` expands to a certain tag or something.

or do I use regex?

Comment: Do you mean like BBCode (XML with brackets ^^)?

Comment: I'm not tied to any given syntax, just an ability to add my own code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears that you can write [extensions](http://www.freewisdom.org/projects/python-markdown/Writing_Extensions) for Python-Markdown, which is probably the best approach.

If you are using some other Markdown implementation (or, you know, just for the heck of it) you could pre-process the text to implement your own tags (converting them to HTML) before handing it off to Markdown. This could be done using a regex or by any method you like. Within reasonable limits, Markdown should [leave your HTML alone](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#html).

Comment: ya, im just worried about leaking unsafe html.

Comment: @Timmy: Then "whitelist, not blacklist" ;) I.e. only expand a very limited set of tags that are known to be safe.

Comment: You can already enter any HTML into Markdown. What you may want to do in that case is sanitize the input by converting `&` into `&amp;` and then `<` into `&lt;` (making all HTML appear as text rather than being rendered) and then, after this step, implement your own tags that produce unescaped HTML.

Comment: You can write extensions for Python-Markdown too, I just discovered. Added this to the top of my answer since it is probably the best approach.